# JSDom Not Running Text as Scripts

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsdom

According to the [JSDom README](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom/tree/3.x), you can pass an array of Javascript Strings to execute, but it seems like this feature isn't working for me.

This is my node app:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var jsdom = require('jsdom-no-contextify');

var scripts = ['manipulate-dom.js'];
var src = scripts.map(function(filename) {
    return fs.readFileSync(filename, 'utf8');
});

console.log(src[0]);

jsdom.env({
    html: '<div>Hi</div>',
    src: src,
    done: function(errors, window) {
        console.log(window.document.querySelector('div').textContent);
        window.doStuff();
        console.log(window.document.querySelector('a').textContent);
    }
});
```

and this is my other file:

```
console.log('Running JS');

function doStuff() {
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.textContent = 'TEXT!';
    window.document.body.appendChild(a);
}

window.doStuff = doStuff;
```

The output is as follows:

```
console.log('Running JS');

function doStuff() {
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.textContent = 'TEXT!';
    window.document.appendChild(a);
}

window.doStuff = doStuff;
Hi

...
        window.doStuff();
               ^
TypeError: Object #<Window> has no method 'doStuff'
```

It doesn't even print "Running JS". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: this is the output that's displaying in the console? or the browser?  if that's what's displaying in the browser, then you're not referencing your "other file" correctly

Comment: @DaRod I'm running Node command-line, and the output quoted is what I saw. The source code in the output is *proof* that I've loaded the second file; the code just isn't getting executed.

Comment: are you using this with node.js or io.js?

Comment: @DaRod Node version 10; JSDom version 3.

Comment: i found this post that may help: https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom/issues/640#issuecomment-22216965 It basically describes that sometimes the scripts haven't finished loading before "done" gets hit.  if this was the case, then window.doStuff= doStuff wouldn't have been assigned before you call window.doStuff(), hence the error.  Try this, instead of assigning calling window.doStuff(), try just calling doStuff() and see if that function is available.  that assignment is redundant anyway.

Comment: @DaRod I tried using `setTimeout` for 5000ms and still the script didn't run. It's as if JSDOM is ignoring it. Removing the redundant code didn't help either.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72443/discussion-between-da-rod-and-acbabis).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try observing what's in the "errors" object.  from the documentation: If window creation succeeds and no s cause errors, then errors will be null, and window will be usable.

Your issue will probably be revealed in there.  =)